# Perl: Different ways to access nested hash keys

Tags: perl, hash

Im almost newbie in Perl. So just wondering about the differences between two ways of accessing a  value in nested hash.

Consider the following hash:

```
my %hsh = ( 
    'fruits' => { 
        'red'    => 'apple', 
        'yellow' => 'banana', 
    },
    'veg' => {
        'red'    => 'capcicum',
        'yellow' => 'lemon',
    },
);

#way 1
print $hsh{'fruits'}{'red'}; 

#way 2
print $hsh{'fruits'}->{'red'};
```

Both has same output `apple`. But what is the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `->` operator is used to de-reference a hash or array reference.  In your case, it is not needed, because Perl assumes de-referencing when dealing with a multidimension data structure.  However in other cases, it is necessary:

```
my $ref = [ 'a','b','c' ];

print $ref[0];    #Fails
print $ref->[0];  #Succeeds
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Perl's philosophy is "There's more than one way to do it".

The `->` is just an explicit dereference. When you omit it, Perl *usually* knows what you mean. There could be cases with large nesting that you'd want to explicitly have it.

**Edit** my post wasn't clear. In this case Perl knows what you mean but as @cHao pointed out there are times when it doesn't.

Comment: Perl still *usually* knows what you mean.  `->` is still required in some places (like between a reference and the first index), but can be omitted between indexes.

Answer (score 0):

`->` is a dereferencing operator; it's used with hash*refs*, not hashes. Hashrefs are used avoid creating a copy of the hash data, which reduces CPU and memory usage.

#### Hashes

Creating a hash:

```
my %hash = ('red' => 'apple');
```

or

```
my %hash = %$hashref;
```

access using:

```
print $hash{'red'};
```

#### Hashrefs

Creating a hashref:

```
my $hashref = { 'red' => 'apple' };
```

or

```
my $hashref = \%hash;
```

access using:

```
print $hashref->{'red'};
```

Comment: A hash ref *is* a references to a hash. It's not used to pass a reference to a hash. And it's impossible to pass a hash to a sub or to return one from a sub, so it's not an alternative to that.